# Rust trait alias

Tags: rust

I am working on a actor project which need alias for the trait because it is so long, but even with the nightly feature `#![feature(trait_alias)]` seems can not achieve.

In short I write a playground:
I want alias `A<T>` to be shorter causing I have many generic type on `A` in real case; and the same time I want to access the `type Output = Self;` from its implementations `B`.
Appreciate for any help.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a9bb8d3f76112c0b73ea1da8af34959

```
#![feature(trait_alias)]

trait A<T> {
    type Output;
    fn test(a: T) -> Self::Output;
}

//To alias the trait, real situation longer than this.
//attempt 1:
trait B: A<String>{}

//attempt 2:
//trait B : A<String, Output=Self> where Self: std::marker::Sized {}
//impl<T> B for T where T: A<String, Output=T> {}

//attempt 3 with trait_alias:
//trait B = A<String>;

struct SA;

impl B for SA {
    type Output = Self;
}
```

Comment: The [unstable book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/trait-alias.html) suggests that `impl TraitAlias for Type` is not supported syntax: "The trait_alias feature adds support for trait aliases. These allow aliases to be created for one or more traits (currently just a single regular trait plus any number of auto-traits), and used **wherever traits would normally be used as either bounds or trait objects** [emphasis added]."

Comment: @CormacO'Brien haha you post this 1s after my answer xd

Comment: "in real case" please demonstrated here, because for now I only see one generic. you said "my problem is that I have too many generic", but doesn't show it in your [mcve] at least show more than 1.

Answer (score 4):

trait alias is only mean to be:

> used wherever traits would normally be used as either bounds or trait objects. [Source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/trait-alias.html)

So, your use case doesn't match, you can't do that.

Comment: Thanks and yes, `#![feature(trait_alias)]` look like so, wondering any alternative way to achieve.

Comment: @raul without know why you want to do what you want to do no.

Comment: No, it's not possible. An `impl` block is neither a trait bound or a trait object - these both relate to function arguments.